# How to access text inside flash object

Tags: c#, flash, firefox

I've got to access text inside a flash object. The preferred method is via C#, but anything that works will do. The only requirement is that I'll need the resulting information to be transferred back to c# code.

Let's take, for example, [this page](http://www.bet365.com/home/FlashGen4/WebConsoleApp.asp).
With [fireflashbug](http://www.o-minds.com/products/flashfirebug), you can easily access individual elements inside flash object and read/change html texts inside each of them.
To work, it requires [Flash Debugger](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).

How can I do the same from my own code?

Comment: The page you say (bet365) doesn't use flash.

Comment: Use an ExternalInterface from the Flash to JavaScript.

Comment: Do you really want us to write an answer that helps you win more money on bet365? I assume you want to be up to date with the latest information that is provided by the web console of your sports bet website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AS3 ExternalInterface with or without JS. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353525/c-and-flash-communication) thread too:
[C# and Flash communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353525/c-and-flash-communication)

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with a flash object you use Javascript.

Here are some tutorial and examples:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface.html

http://csl.sublevel3.org/howto/javascript_flash_callbacks/

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/

Now, once you have your data using javascript you can pass them to an input element and pass it to code behind if you wish for.

and many more [on google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=communicate+flash+with+javascript)